# Repository is not being mocked JUnit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, mockito, junit5

I'm encountering the following error when I run the unit test:
Error:java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.gerenciadordetarefas.repository.task.TaskRepository.findById(Object)" because "this.taskRepository" is null

I know that the repository is not being mocked, but I don't know why.

TaskServiceTest

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TaskServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private TaskRepository repository;

    @InjectMocks
    private  TaskService service;

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;
    private static final String TASK_ID_1 = "652d960af866034b686cca97";
    private static final String TASK_ID_2 = "252d960af866034b686cca92";
    private static final String USER_ID_1 = "642f6ab6813d692cef4795cc";

    private final User user1 = User.builder()
            .id(USER_ID_1)
            .name("Maria Silva")
            .assignedTasks(new ArrayList<>())
            .build();
    private final Task task = Task.builder()
            .title("teste")
            .description("teste aqui")
            .dateOfCreation(LocalDate.now())
            .dueDate(LocalDate.now())
            .assigne(Collections.singletonList(user1))
            .build();

    private final TaskDto taskD = TaskDto.builder()
            .title("teste")
            .description("teste aqui")
            .dateOfCreation(LocalDate.now())
            .dueDate(LocalDate.now())
            .assigne(Collections.singletonList(USER_ID_1))
            .build();



    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        // MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        service = new TaskService(userService);
        Mockito.lenient().when(userService.getUserById(USER_ID_1)).thenReturn(user1);
        Mockito.lenient().when(repository.save(Mockito.any(Task.class))).thenReturn(task);
        Mockito.lenient().when(repository.findById(TASK_ID_1)).thenReturn(Optional.of(task));
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Verificar se o objeto Task está sendo criado ")
    void createTask() {
        service.createTask(taskD);
        verify(repository, times(1)).save(task);

    }
```

TaskService:

```
@Service
public class TaskService {
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;
    private final UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    public TaskService(@Lazy UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public TaskDtoResponse createTask(TaskDto taskDto) {
        Task task = TaskMapper.taskDtoToTask(taskDto);
        this.addToAssigne(taskDto, task);
        taskRepository.save(task);
        return TaskMapper.taskToTaskDtoResponse(task);
    }
    public Task addToAssigne(TaskDto taskDto, Task task){
        List<String>assigne = taskDto.getAssigne();
        assigne.forEach(id -> {
            User user = userService.getUserById(id);
            task.getAssigne().add(user);
        });
        return task;
    }
}
```

TaskRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends MongoRepository<Task, String> {
    @Query("{_id: {$in:?0}})")
    List<Task> findByIds(List<String> ids);
}
```

UserService:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;


    public UserDtoResponse createUser(UserDto userDto)  {
        User user = UserMapper.userDtoToUser(userDto);
        if(userDto.getAssignedTasks() != null){
            this.addToTaskList(userDto, user);
        }
        userRepository.save(user);
        return UserMapper.userToUserDtoResponse(user);
    }
    public User addToTaskList(UserDto userDto, User user){
        List<String>assignedTasks =  userDto.getAssignedTasks();
        assignedTasks.forEach(id-> {
            Task task = taskService.getTaskById(id);
            user.getAssignedTasks().add(task);
        });
        return user;
    }
}
```

How can I make the test createTask() pass?

Comment: When you create a new `taskService` in `setUp`, you are replacing the instance of `TaskService` which had the mocks injected.

Comment: I suggest using constructor injection, by the way. That would have made this problem clearer.

Comment: Even after removing service = new TaskService(userService), the error persists.
Implementing dependency injection in TaskService like that because I was having a circular dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

Issue you have here is that you are overriding the TaskService to which you have injected the mocks. You create new instance of it in the setup.

If possible you can have something like this

```
@Mock
Repository repository;
@Mock
OtherService otherService;
TaskService service;

@Setup
void setup() {
    service = new TaskService(repository, otherService);
}
```

If you can not inject the repository using constructor injection, then you can do what you did previously, but inject the other service the same way you inject your repository.

Third option you have is to set the other service via setter in the task service, but I would not recommend doing this.

Comment: They should be able to just remove the line `service = new TaskService(userService);`. I expect Mockito will do field and ctor injection simultaneously.

Comment: Even after removing service = new TaskService(userService), the error persists.

Comment: Exactly the same error?

Comment: Yes, the same error

Comment: I found out what was causing the error.The @Autowired was being ignored due to the @Autowired in the constructor, so I refactored it and it looks like this:`
`TaskService {
    private final TaskRepository taskRepository;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public TaskService(@Lazy UserService userService, TaskRepository taskRepository) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.taskRepository = taskRepository;
    }
}`